# Is there an equivalent to Django's reverse URL lookup in Java Struts framework?

Tags: java, django, struts

I want to find out whether there is a Struts equivalent to Django's reverse URL lookup, where you can associate names to URL patterns and refer to these in your code. This allows you to change the URLs easily, since all of them are defined at a single location (urls.py)

That is, a way to assign names to URL patterns, and then be able to generate a correct URL from the name and values for the replacement parameters.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse